# PXE disk wipe utility?

Tags: security, pxe

I know that DBAN is easily used if you have a CD/DVD/USB drive.  However, if you have a situation where one is unable to have physical access a network bootable situation is needed.  So is there an PXE bootable DBAN type of program available?  Or is there some way to make DBAN an PXE type of load?

Comment: Before I post the wrong thing: did you mean PXE boot? Because there are solutions to PXE boot DBAN. Otherwise, someone smarter than me can surely help. :-)

Comment: It looks like you're looking to run DBAN from a network boot, and while IPX is a network protocol it's doubtful that's what you actually meant. As JSanchez mentioned, you're probably looking for a PXE boot solution for running DBAN.

Comment: Yes, what was I thinking about PXE boot is one that I am looking for.  Thanks for the correction. :-)

Comment: Do you already have a PXE server you need to add DBAN too?  Is this meant to be a temporary setup?  What are you currently doing for a DHCP server?  This should really easy to setup.  Setup a tftp server, pxelinux, get the dban image, and configure it all the right way.

Comment: I have a PXE server...I have a DHCP server....So specifically what do I need to do to make a PXE image that can be used on a number of different machines?

Answer (score 1):

We PXE boot the WipeDrive commercial product. We have a Windows Deployment Services (WDS) server, but it loads PXELinux before the user is presented with the WDS menu. (So this should work from a straight PXELinux server as well). It's from the PXELinux menu that we present our technicians with the WipeDrive option.

There are plenty of how-tos for setting up PXELinux on WDS, so I'll skip that part. Here is the portion of our PXELinux config file that creates the WipeDrive menu option.

```
LABEL WipeDrive
 MENU PASSWD you_might_want_a_password_here
 MENU LABEL WipeDrive PRO
 TEXT HELP
  Wipes a hard drive like nobody's business.
 ENDTEXT
 KERNEL memdisk keeppxe
 APPEND iso initrd=WipeDrive.iso
```

The last two lines are the important ones. Specifically, the last line tells PXELinux which ISO image to load.

I've never tried this with DBAN, but we boot other ISO images also, so there's hope for DBAN working.